# Mayim Achronim according to the Rama

Tags: ashkenazi, netilat-yadayim-washing, bentching, shulchan-aruch

The Rama in his Darkei Moshe writes that we pasken like Tosfos that today mayim achronim is not necessary.

However, The Mechaber 181:10 writes that there is an opinion who holds we don't do mayim achronim, but the Rama does not say anything on this se'if, why doesn't the Rama say *V'haci Noheg* like in the Darkei Moshe?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is such a strong question. The Rama doesn't comment on everything

Comment: The Rama is totally absent from this siman,and he mentions it in his Darkei Moshe ,its not a small halacha,wouldn't you think a vachi noheg would make it in at least?

Comment: Not necessarily. Plenty of times the Rama doesn't bring everything down in the Mapah.

Comment: I understand that,but when it is one shittah which holds like that ,I would think it is necessary,but what do I know,that's why I am curious.

Comment: Consider for instance the Darkei Moshe OC 127

Comment: Why do you think that the רמ"א would say והכי נהוג? Maybe it's not true....? maybe the Minhag was to yes do מים אחרונים even if we pasken like Tosafos.

Comment: @DannySchoemann The formulation in the Darkei Moshe is "מיהו המנהג כדברי התוספות"

Comment: @DoubleAA: Thanks. that clarifies the question.